# MVC EntityFramework user roles are not coming through in context

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following models:

User:

```
public class User : IEntity, INamedType
    {
        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public int AreaId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        //Navigation properties
        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

Role:

```
public class Role : IEntity
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        //Navigation Properties
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

UserRole:

```
public class UserRole
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        //Navigation properties
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a CustomRoleProvider with this method:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            var user = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetUser(username);

            var roles = from r in user.Roles
                        select r.Name;

            if (roles != null)
                return roles.ToArray();
            else
                return new string[] { };
        }
```

so this all works fine until a an entry is added or removed from the `UserRole` table. For the `User` this record relates to the new Role when added by adding a `UserRole` row does not come through in the `GetRolesForUser` method. Likewise if a `UserRole` record is removed the `Role` keeps coming through for the record.

If however an IISReset occurs then all the correct records come through.

Anyone know why this would be happening and how to rectify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserRole` entity class conflicts with the join table created by EF for the many to many relationship.

You should either remove the `UserRole` entity or map the relationships in `User` and `Role` to the join entity

```
public class User : IEntity, INamedType
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}


public class Role : IEntity
{
     public int RoleId { get; set; }

     //Navigation Properties
     public ICollection<UserRole> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an idea. I can see your point that the UserRole shouldn't even be in there. However I think it is require because you need access to this table to add roles to users or remove them. Not sure if the mapping you have there is the best though because now Users and Roles don't return collections of their actual type but collections of UserRole